# Passing json object to spring mvc controller using Ajax

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to send a json via Ajax request to a Spring mvc controller without success.
The json string has the following form:

```
{"Books": 
   [{'author':'Murakami','title':'Kafka on the shore'},{'author':'Murakami','title':'Norwegian Wood'}]}
```

The controller that parses the json wraps it through this java bean:

```
class Books{
   List <Map<String, String>> books;
   //...get & set method of the bean
}
```

The controller method has the following form:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST }, value = "/checkBook.do")
public ModelAndView callCheckBook(
        @RequestBody Books books){....}
```

Unfortunately this does not work, I get the following error when invoking the method:
"Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name..."

Where am I getting wrong?
Thank you in advance!
Regards

Comment: What version of spring are you using?  Also provide the script that creates the ajax request.

Comment: spring version 3.0.4, the js code is the following: $.post('checkBook.do', $.parseJSON(jsonString), function(data) {..}

Comment: post more code of callCheckBook method.

Comment: the callCheckBookMethod body is not reached, I think the problem is before in the deserialization of the Books object...

Answer (score 0):

create a Model class

```
class Books
{
private string author;
private string title;
// gets and sets
}
```

And Also create Wrapper class like this

```
class BookWrapper{
private List<Books> Books; // this name should matches the json header
}
```

Now in controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST }, value = "/checkBook.do")
public ModelAndView callCheckBook(
        @RequestBody BookWrapper Books){....}
```

in Ajax call create a seralizeArray of you forum this will give you json object and then it will bind to the wrapper class